# Calling a function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a function that passes two string arguments and returns string type and I am calling the same function through a sub. I am getting an error with the arguments suggesting argument mismatch whereas I checked and the arguments are correct. Cant see to understand where the problem is. Can someone please help out . Here is the code

```
    Sub TableCat()
    Dim Key As String
    Worksheets("Table").Activate
    Call RemoveDupes
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
     TableMode = Application.Trim(ActiveCell.Value)
     TableId = Application.Trim(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value)
     ControlID = Application.Trim(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value)
     Key = ControlID & TableId
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TableCatCalling(Key, TableMode)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    End Sub
```

The function

```
    Function TableCatCalling(Key As String, Mode As String) As String
    Dim CatCell As Range
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Worksheets("CCM Analysisv2").Activate
    Set searchRange = Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))
    Set CatCell = searchRange.Find(what:=Key, lookAt:=xlWhole)
    If CatCell Is Nothing Then
     TableCatCalling = " "
    Else
     If TableMode Like "New" Then
        TableCatCalling = CatCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
     End If
    End If
    Worksheets("Table").Activate
    End Function
```

Comment: Declare your variables.  (Use `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code module to force you to do so.)  Declare `TableMode As String` and I think your problems will go away (assuming that you are getting a "ByRef argument type mismatch" error at `TableCatCalling(Key, TableMode)`).

Comment: try changing `Key` and `Mode` to `iKey` and `iMode`

Comment: Also note that you are using an undefined variable `TableMode` in your function.  That is probably intended to be `Mode`.  Again, `Option Explicit` would tell you about that typo and force you to fix it before you spend hours scratching your head wondering why the code isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: You may also want to pass the range arguments. With that you dont need to activate the other workbook, and you can do it with other workbooks.

Comment: my intuition tells me that using `activate`, `select`, `activecell` , and not referencing ranges/cells with the sheet , are the culprit, again....

Comment: @YowE3K Yes you are right I am getting the "ByRef.." error message . I tried using the option explicit also bu I am still getting this error.

Comment: @prernaarora `Option Explicit` just enables you to detect (and therefore prevent) errors easier - it won't correct the error.  To correct your error you need to declare `TableMode As String` rather than letting it default to `Variant`.  A `Variant` variable can not be passed as a parameter defined `ByRef` (by default) `As String`. (The `Option Explicit` will be forcing you to declare it as **something**, so make sure it is as `String`.)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue appears to be because you are passing a variable of type `Variant` to a `ByRef` (by default) parameter of type `String`.

You should get into the habit of always declaring your variables.  Use `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code module to force you to do it.

The code below:

- declares `TableMode` (plus a few other variables that weren't declared),
- fixes up the error in your function where you were using a variable (`TableMode`) which had never been declared or assigned a value.
- gets rid of most of the uses of `Activate`, `ActiveCell` (by introducing a specific variable called `CurrentCell`) and `Select`

Hopefully it resolves your problems.

```
'Use "Option Explicit" to force you to declare variables
Option Explicit

Sub TableCat()
    'Declare variables that weren't declared before
    Dim TableMode As String
    Dim TableId As String
    Dim ControlID As String
    Dim CurrentCell As Range

    Dim Key As String
    'These two lines should be replaced with something which doesn't
    'use Activate and ActiveCell
    Worksheets("Table").Activate
    Set CurrentCell = ActiveCell

    RemoveDupes
    Do Until CurrentCell.Value = ""
        TableMode = Application.Trim(CurrentCell.Value)
        TableId = Application.Trim(CurrentCell.Offset(0, -1).Value)
        ControlID = Application.Trim(CurrentCell.Offset(0, -2).Value)
        Key = ControlID & TableId
        CurrentCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TableCatCalling(Key, TableMode)
        Set CurrentCell = CurrentCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub

Function TableCatCalling(Key As String, Mode As String) As String
    Dim CatCell As Range
    Dim searchRange As Range
    With Worksheets("CCM Analysisv2") 'Avoid activating the worksheet
        Set searchRange = .Range("C1", .Range("C1").End(xlDown))
    End With
    Set CatCell = searchRange.Find(what:=Key, lookAt:=xlWhole)
    If CatCell Is Nothing Then
        TableCatCalling = " "
    Else
        'This should refer to "Mode", not "TableMode"
        If Mode Like "New" Then
            TableCatCalling = CatCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
        'Note: You are not setting a return value if "Mode" is not like "New"
        'so your function will return "" by default
    End If
End Function
```